# Will the Java 7 JRE be pushed out as an automatic update to people running the Java 6 JRE?

Tags: java

I believe a precedent for this must exist... when the Java 6 JRE was released, were users of the Java 5 JRE automatically updated to Java 6 JRE?

Or to put it another way, are automatic update capable of moving you from one major version to another (e.g. from JRE 5 --> JRE 6), or do they just update the "maintenance" releases within a version (e.g. JRE 1.6.0_25 --> 1.6.0_26)?

Comment: Probably should go to SO.

Comment: A similar question was asked on SO and told to move here!

Comment: It's absolutely fine to stay here. Java is something not only programmers have installed.

Comment: @cagcowboy, thanks for finally getting some kind of answer to my question.  Rather shocked that it was closed here too.

Comment: I think this depends on the OS.  Microsoft can do it differently that Apple, and all of the different Linux distributions have their own policies.

Comment: Excellent point KeithB.  In our case it's the standard Windows JRE from Oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the latter: If you had version 5, you had to download version 6 separately. At least in the past, it only updated maintenance releases. It is hard to say if version 6 will actually update to version 7 though since it has not happened yet.

Comment: I hate java updates period.

Comment: This is actually wrong. JRE 5 did update to JRE 6, although only a few updates in. Security updates are synchronised between releases.